# installing DR java on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation

I will be attending computer science classes and we are asked to be using `DrJava`, but am using linux os and I don't know how to install `DrJava` on ubuntu. Please help me.
I tried to download a jar file for `DrJava` and run below command

```
java-jar drjava-stable-20190813-220051
```

But this is the response I get;

> Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install default-jre            
> sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
> sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

And try again.